# Use a variable taken from ShinyApp in a Rscript

Tags: r, variables, input, shiny, reactive

I would like to insert the value of a variable in a Shiny app and call it from a R script, but I don't know how to modify the script ("myscript.R") in order to receive the variable ("text") from the app.

This is an example of my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyBS)

source("myscript.R", local = TRUE)
```

**UI**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
   
  wellPanel(
   fluidRow(
    textInput(inputId = "text", label = "Insert your name...", value = ""),
    actionButton("runScript", "Run")
    ),
  ),
)
```

**Server**

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  mylist <- reactiveVal()
  
  observe({ 
    mylist(list(
      text = input$text))
    })
  
  observeEvent(input$runScript, { 
    source("myscript.R", local = list2env(mylist()))
  })
}
```

**R script**

```
myscript <- function(text) 
{ 
  myname <- text
  print(myname)   # I have simplified my code...The use of the variable "text" is more complex
}
```

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source your myscript.R program outside the server, and then call the function inside the `observeEvent(...)` as shown below.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  wellPanel(
    fluidRow(
      textInput(inputId = "text", label = "Insert your name...", value = ""),
      actionButton("runScript", "Run")
    ),
  ),
)

source("myscript.R", local = TRUE)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  mylist <- reactiveVal()
  
  observe({ 
    mylist(list(
      text = input$text))
    #print(mylist())
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$runScript, { 
    myscript(mylist())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```